# Using a Dummy Variable to Control for Great Recession data

Tags: multiple-regression, categorical-data, econometrics, panel-data

I am looking to produce a forecast with a quarterly dataset of sales. I only have so many year's worth of data post-recession and I want to investigate including more datapoints, which would mean using pre-recession, and mid-recession (2008 - 2009 Q2) data in my multiple regression model.

In addition to my quarterly dummy variables, is it acceptable to use another dummy for quarters during the recession period (ie. assigning 0 to all quarters outside of the recesstion time period and a 1 for those quarters within)? I want to be able to control for the effect of the recession and have a more accurate forecast for sales. Is there a better way to control for this effect of the recession on sales, or is it more worthwhile to compare the larger model with the dummy variable vs. the smaller model without the dummy variable (only post-recession)? Any thoughts or insight would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I think that what you are proposing is a diff-in-diff with the OLS, in alternative you could introduce lagged dependent variables in your model (but that would require a certain number of years that it seems you do not have) or a research discontinuity design. It depends on the specific data and control variables that you have, I believe.

I think a good reading that might help you is:
Angrist, J. D., & Pischke, J. S. (2008). Mostly harmless econometrics: An empiricist's companion. Princeton university press.
More precisely, I would suggest you to take a look into chapters 5 and 6.